# How to get state in react after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-context

I am trying to fetch data from firebase. I am able to get the data and update the state, but state returns undefined after render in my React context Provider. I have tried to use some of the Life cycle method like componentWillMount or calling my fetchData function my the constructor function , since it get called before render, but none is working. Below is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { dataDB, productDetail } from './data';
import { db } from './config/fbConfig'
import { TimerSharp } from '@material-ui/icons';

const ProductContext = React.createContext();
class ProductProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            products: []
           
        }

        this.fetchData()

    }

       fetchData = () => {
        db.collection("projects")
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
                console.log(data); //successfully returns the data
                // this.setState({ projects: data });
                this.setState(() => {
                    return {
                        projects: data
                    }
                })
                console.log(this.state.products) // successfully returns the data and update the state
            });
    }


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.products) // returns empty arr and I  need it to return the updated state with data
        return (
            <ProductContext.Provider value={{

                ...this.state
                
            }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ProductContext.Provider>
        )

    }
}

const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;
export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

The issue is this.state.products get called before calling data in firebase. Please how can I be able to get data after render.

Comment: Upon first render, it will not have loaded your data yet (due to your fetch being an asynchronous process), so you have to verify you have actually loaded the data (verify if it's null or empty or default value). Also, best practices wise, you should fetch your data in the `componentDidMount()` lifetime method and not in the constructor

Comment: Your initial state is {products:[]}, but then you update it with {projects:someData}. `products` is not updated.

Comment: @Icepickle, I actually verified it , if it has received data, but return null does not help as I need the state as a global variable in other components . I also called fetchData in componentDidMount() but same issue

Comment: @windowsill products was actually updated when I console logged the state when fetchData is called , but the products return empty array after render, and that's where I need it , so as to pass it as a global variable to other components.

Answer (score 0):

In `fetchData()` you set the attribute `this.state.projects` but in `render` you log `this.state.products`

Comment: it's a typo but state still returns empty products after render